# IIS 8.5, .NET 6 WebApi Controller does not work(500) while wwwroot files does

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0, windows-server-2012-r2

I have **WebApi .Net 6** added to **IIS**, but controllers doesn't work.

I turned on static files to be sure if the problem in Runtimes whatever, but images **work** by the link, so the app is working(?). In Task Manager i can see running tasks of the app.

1. I tried to turn on logging in **web.config**, *no logs*.
2. I installed **Serilog** expecting it will write logs as i see in console, but *nothing was written*, i guess it's because IIS runs .dll instead of .exe.
3. I tried manually create files on each step of the app, *nothing was created*....

So at this point i am stuck completely. Don't understand what the
problem is.

When i run .exe of my app ***on the server***, ***everything works by localhost link***.

Release files created by the command: ***dotnet publish -c release***

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**UPDATE**

The problem was that i missed '/' in a file path...
You can turn on app to show errors via web.config:
[image]

Comment: have you installed the hosting bundle? on IIS

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi, i know about the hosting bundle but couldn't find on internet how can i check whether it installed :(
Can't you see it on the first screenshot?

Comment: I just checked it through regedit, everything installed. I will update the main post.

Comment: Can you show your startup (or program) file pls?

Comment: @Serge hi, sure. I've updated the post you can see screenshots.

Comment: You can use failed request tracking to view detailed error information about 500.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the answer in the main post in Update.